# Can't upsert fields (numeric names) in nested document with custom conversions

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

mongooperations.upsert is calling MongoTemplate using query:

`{ "_id" : "1"} and update: { "$set" : { "node" : "changed"}}`

instead of valid

`{ "_id" : "1"} and update: { "$set" : { "node.1" : "changed"}}`

The node document is jackson ObjectNode converted to HashMap then to BasicDBObject in write converter. Node's keys are numbers - with strings it works properly. I'm using

`mongoOperations.upsert(query, update,Domain::class.java)`

and it prepares invalid query. After changing to

`mongoOperations.upsert(query, update,"domain")`

query is being prepared properly.

Also when working on BasicDBObjects - query is valid.

How can conversions influence query creation?